# jquery multiselect selectedList not wrapping with IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, multi-select

Using Eric Hynds' Jquery Multiselect widget under IE9 the display of the selectList items is not wrapped like it should be.

IE9:

[image]

Expected:

[image]

I'm sure it has something to do with quirks mode but I haven't been able to track down how to fix this. I am using `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`because I also am using some HTML5 features for the browsers that can.

Anyone have suggestions on how to get it to wrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **quirks mode** is your problem use that meta in your head tag:

```
<head>
  ...
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  ...
</head>
```